# Invoke my forms method from my custom control within my other custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, events, user-controls

Had a look on here and found several examples but they don't seem to fit my exact problem and through experimentation I can't work it out.

Current code for form...

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DualCombo dc = new DualCombo();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Controls.Add(dc);
        }

        private void MyMethod()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dc.c1.Text + dc.c2.Text);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }
    }
```

The control that contains 2 of my custom combos...

```
public class DualCombo : UserControl
    {
        public CustomCombo c1 = new CustomCombo();
        public CustomCombo c2 = new CustomCombo();
        public DualCombo()
        {

                c1.Items.Add("One");
                c1.Items.Add("Two");
                c1.Items.Add("Three");


                c2.Left = c1.Right;
                c2.Items.Add("One");
                c2.Items.Add("Two");
                c2.Items.Add("Three");

            this.Controls.Add(c1);
            this.Controls.Add(c2);
        }

    }
```

I have left the code from the custom combo blank to keep the example simple...

```
public class CustomCombo : ComboBox
    {


    }
```

I would like my custom combo OnSelectedIndex changed to trigger the following method that is in the form...

```
 private void MyMethod()
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dc.c1.Text + dc.c2.Text);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to subscribe to that event directly:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.Add(dc);
    dc.c1.SelectionChangedEvent += (s, e) => MyMethod();
}
```

But this is bad idea to make `c1` public, read further.

---

`UserControl` is encapsulated control with some functionality. If you need to inform someone who is using that `UserControl` about something simple create an event:

Add event to `UserControl`

```
public EventHandler SomeEvent;
protected void OnSomeEvent() => SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Fire it when selection is changed from within `UserControl`

```
 protected CustomCombo c1 = new CustomCombo();
 public DualCombo()
 {
     c1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => OnSomeEvent();
     ...
 }
```

Now you can subscribe to that event in your form (where this `UserControl` is used):

```
DualCombo dc = new DualCombo();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.Add(dc);
    dc.SomeEvent += (s, e) => MyMethod(); // call your method
}
```

Tips: do not make controls inside `UserControl` `public`. Think about `UserControl` as a black box.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. However I get OnSomeEvent does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Where do you call it? Perhaps you have written by mistake `dc.OnSomeEvent += ...` (should be `dc.SomeEvent += ...`)?

Comment: it's in the dual combo c1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => OnSomeEvent();

Comment: ok got it working i was putting this... public EventHandler SomeEvent;
protected void OnSomeEvent() => SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); in the custom combo rather than the dual combo